# last_error_message item in telegram webhook

Tags: bots

The connection between my server and the Telegram server has been interrupted.

In Telegram's webhook last_error_message and last_error_date removed and I can't understood where is the problem.

```
    ok  true
result  
url "https://example.com/orders/index.php"
has_custom_certificate  false
pending_update_count    0
max_connections 40
ip_address  "xxx.xx.xxx.xx"
```

Can someone help me ?